# configure snappy (sentinel application platform) python package with qgis python interpreter, am using pycharm as IDE

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, snap

i have a problem related to setup a pycharm env to use qgis python interpreter and configure snappy (sentinel application platform) python package with the same interpreter.

already tried to install OSGeo4W (python 3.9, QGIS:3.30) and configured snappy package, i got this error:

```
> snappy-conf C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Lib\


The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.
Configuring SNAP-Python interface...
java.io.IOException: Python configuration failed.
Command [C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe .\snappyutil.py --snap_home "C:\Program Files\snap" --java_module C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\SNAP\modules\org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file .\snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 11G --java_home "C:\Program Files\snap\jre\jre" --req_arch amd64]
failed with return code 10.
Please check the log file 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Lib\snappy\snappyutil.log'.
        at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.configureJpy(PyBridge.java:232)
        at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.installPythonModule(PyBridge.java:149)
        at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.processPython(SnapArgsProcessor.java:103)
        at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.process(SnapArgsProcessor.java:49)
        at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:202)
        at org.netbeans.spi.sendopts.Option$1.process(Option.java:387)
        at org.netbeans.api.sendopts.CommandLine.process(CommandLine.java:317)
        at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.HandlerImpl.execute(HandlerImpl.java:62)
        at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.Handler.cli(Handler.java:69)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLICoreBridge.cli(CLICoreBridge.java:82)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$1.exec(CLIHandler.java:268)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.finishInitialization(CLIHandler.java:447)
        at org.netbeans.MainImpl.finishInitialization(MainImpl.java:256)
        at org.netbeans.Main.finishInitialization(Main.java:92)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:316)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Python configuration error: Python configuration failed.
Command [C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe .\snappyutil.py --snap_home "C:\Program Files\snap" --java_module C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\SNAP\modules\org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file .\snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 11G --java_home "C:\Program Files\snap\jre\jre" --req_arch amd64]
failed with return code 10.
Please check the log file 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Lib\snappy\snappyutil.log'.
```